# Calling a C++ function from Java JNI - Cocos2d-x

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, google-play-services

I am working on a project in **Cocos2d-x (Latest)** in which I worked with Google Play Game Services, I encountered several problems when I tried to integrate Google Play Services with C++ and then I decided to change to JAVA.

When the **user** click to the **Button** "Invite Friend", the **method startGame()** is called successfully with JNI, but nothing happening ! The following scene does not display.

**C++ Code :**

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sonar_systems_frameworks_GooglePlayServices_GooglePlayServicesGameHelper_startGame(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz);
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sonar_systems_frameworks_GooglePlayServices_GooglePlayServicesGameHelper_startGame(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{

    MenuScene::goToScene();

}
void MenuScene::goToScene() {

    //Going to the next scene
    Scene * gameScene=GameScene::createScene();
    TransitionFade*transition=TransitionFade::create(TRANSITION_TIME, gameScene);
    //Replace the current Scene with New Game Scene
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(transition);
}
```

**Java Code from where the above function is called :**

```
private native void startGame();
public void inviteFriend() {

    startGame();

    // launch the player selection screen
    // minimum: 1 other player; maximum: 3 other players
    //Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 1);
    //((Activity) GooglePlayServices.ctx).startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);

}
```

The communication between C++ and Java is fine, but why I cannot to go to next scene, the code is correct !

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, It seems like he needs to execute in CocosThread so I did like that :

```
 Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->performFunctionInCocosThread([&](){
        MenuScene::goToScene();
    });
```